# Vue 3 local component library (sfc) development not working due to Plugins not reloading

Tags: vuejs3, quasar, hot-reload, vue-sfc, vue3-sfc-loader

I need help. I'm developing a `vue-3` (Quasar/Electron) app with a separate component library. What I'm trying to get working is to develop the component library locally alongside the main app with hot reload.

It's pretty simple, I already have the component library configured as a Vue plugin. If I push to NPM and add it to my project as an npm dependency, everything works fine. What doesn’t work is when I use `yarn link` to symlink locally and then add it the same way:

```
import { MyComponentLib } from 'my-component-lib';

app.use(MyComponentLib);
```

This worked fine on `vue-2` as any changes to the local component lib would get **reloaded and immediately shown during development**. However with `vue-3`, you can only load a plugin once (even in development). After the first load you will get a warning: "[Vue warn]: Plugin has already been applied to target app.".

You basically need to **restart the app everytime to see changes** to your local component library. Does anyone know how to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

Setup your project with pnpm workspaces. it will make your life easier. https://pnpm.io/workspaces